# Is Core Data using the Ghost pattern?

Tags: iphone, core-data

All this fault and faulting stuff appears to look pretty much like the Ghost pattern. Is that the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, based on the wikipedia definition of the ghost pattern, that is correct.

Note that you can change that behavior as needed via the NSFetchRequest.